# Gemini API: Supplied value is not a valid DateTime

Tags: python

I am attempting to call an endpoint provided by the [Gemini REST API to extract FX rates](https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#fx-rate), but it kept throwing this error message:

> {'result': 'error', 'reason': 'Bad Request', 'message': "Supplied
> value '1495127793000' is not a valid DateTime"}

Code:

```
base_url = "https://api.gemini.com"
fx_url = base_url + '/v2/fxrate/gbpusd/1495127793000'
fxpayload =  {
    "request": "/v2/fxrate", 
}
fxheaders = create_headers(fxpayload)
response = requests.get(fx_url, headers=fxheaders)
print(response.json()
```

Note that for that endpoint, the docs did state that the [timestamp](https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#timestamps) path should be of `timestamp` type, which the docs also indicated "whole number (milliseconds)". I believe I have provided it in the right format but still throwing errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that timestamp needs to be in the ISO 8601 format, ie `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ` format.

Substituting `1495127793000` with `2017-05-17T17:16:33+0000` and updating payload to the following works:

```
fx_url = base_url + '/v2/fxrate/gbpusd/2017-05-17T17:16:33+0000'
fxpayload =  {
    "request": "/v2/fxrate/gbpusd/2017-05-17T17:16:33+0000", 
}
```